# Lossless rotation of PDF files with imagemagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, image-rotation, lossless

I want to rotate a 351K PDF named `08-file.pdf` using CLI tools. I've tried [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
convert 08-file.pdf -rotate 90 08-file-rotated.pdf
```

But the original quality:

[image]

Suffered serious degradation:

[image]

[I've tried adding the `-density 300x300` argument](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8971), but the outcome was a 2.5M file, nearly one order of magnitude larger than the original, which is a huge waste.

**Any idea how to losslessly rotate a PDF file using imagemagick?**

Comment: ImageMagick does not work directly on PDFs. A note on its "supported formats" page says it "uses ghostScript to convert the file"; presumably, to a simple bitmap, so it can works its magick on it. Then the result can be written to a variety of bitmap formats, of which PDF is just one of them. Use a tool specifically designed to work with PDFs.

Comment: I would try Ghostscript directly.

Comment: Imagemagick and Ghostscript both rasterize the PDF. So if you rotate the PDF and try to write back to PDF, then the original PDF will be rasterize, rotated, then the raster result put into a vector PDF shell. This is not a good way. If you want to improve quality, then increase the density before reading the pdf and then resize appropriately. `convert -density 288 08-file.pdf -rotate 90 -resize 25% 08-file-rotated.pdf`. But I would suggest you look for pure PDF vector tools to do that. You did not post your original PDF, so we cannot test with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always had bad results in converting/altering pdf file with imagemagik/convert (bad resolution, or huge file). Playing with options *-compress -density -quality* was always frustrating and a waste of time (but i am no expert).

#### Proposal 1: pdftk

So I would recommend **pdftk** (you may need to install it via apt-get install)

Try :

```
pdftk  08-file.pdf cat 1-endright output 08-file-rotated.pdf
```

*For old version of pdftk (v<3) rotation was indicated only by one letter:
N: 0, E: 90, S: 180, W: 270, L: -90, R: +90, D: +180. The same command was:*

```
pdftk  08-file.pdf cat 1-endR output 08-file-rotated.pdf
```

From another post on this site, I have a brief an explanation of the syntax

```
pdftk input.pdf cat 1-endsouth output output.pdf
#     \_______/     \___/\___/        \________/
#     input file    range  |          output file
#                         direction
```

You can see also https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk

*Edit 2020*:

#### Proposal 2: qpdf

I have found another alternative which is equivalent: **qpdf**, easier to remember and more powerful

see [QPDF manual](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```
#Syntax (you can rotate only some pages of the document -- see the manual --
qpdf --rotate=[+|-]angle[:page-range]

# Example
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --rotate=+180
```

#### Other options worth to consider

###### [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam)

PDF manipulation tools (CLI)
To be considered if pdftk is not available on your system.

**pdfjam** looks quite similar to **pdftk**

###### [pdfsam](https://pdfsam.org/)

This is a toolbox to modify pdf files with a GUI (graphical user interface).

Code is open source and multiplateform.

[image]

Comment: `convert` does work and one can compress losslessly (which actually reduces the filesize depending on encoding).

Answer (score 4):

Please use `-compress lossless` option:

```
convert -rotate 90 -compress lossless 08-file.pdf 08-file-rotated.pdf
```

From the documentation:
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress

> Lossless refers to lossless JPEG, which is only available if the JPEG
> library has been patched to support it.

Another option is to use the following command:

> jhead -cmd "jpegtran -progressive -perfect -rotate 270 &i > &o"
> Image-0001.jpeg

It will write output to a temporary file and when it succeeds it will overwrite the original file:

> Cmd:jpegtran -progressive -perfect -rotate 270 "Image-0001.jpeg" >
> "h1xQ6q"
>
> Modified: Image-0001.jpeg

Comment: the convert with -compress lossless degrades the quality. I'll prefer to open the file in GIMP, rotate it, then Print it with "Print as File" option. This is the best work around I found.

Comment: `-compress jpeg` worked for me. My issue was file size.